# C++ I'm having some problems with arrays/dynamic memory

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, indexing, copy

so I'm making a lame little snowboarding game (which is what all my questions have been about) and I'm having some issues. 
I have a Biome class, which has a dynamic array to store the possible obstacles for that biome (obstsInBiome). Here is the constructor:

```
Biome::Biome(Obstacle obsts[], int amountOfObsts)
{
    maxObstAmount = 10; // Max amount of obstacles to spawn in each biome
    obstAmount = amountOfObsts; // The amount of obstacles passed in in the obsts parameter

    // This part copys the array passed in to the obstsInBiome array (Class member to store obstacles)
    // I think this is where the error may be
    obstsInBiome = new Obstacle [amountOfObsts]; // Creating array to hold the possible obstacles in this biome
    for (int x = 0; x < amountOfObsts; x++) // Filling the obstacle array with the obstacles passed in
    {
        obstsInBiome[x] = obsts[x];
    }
}
```

Then to create a new biome, i use this:

```
Obstacle villageObsts[] = {tree, rock, cabin, log}; // tree, rock, and cabin are all Obstacles
Biome village(villageObsts, 4);
```

Somewhere within this code, the first element of obstsInBiome is not getting set properly.
 `village.obstsInBiome[0]` is what I mean.

When i try to draw that to the screen, it doesn't appear and invisible collisions happen with the player as if they hit the obstacle. The rest of the array (rock, cabin, and log) all work perfectly. `village.obstsInBiome[1 through 3]` all work fine.

Can someone point out the error in this code?

Comment: you realize that the villageObsts sub objects are being created by copy, right, and that if you modify the obsts that are being passed elsewhere, that won't affect the ones contained in obstsInBiome

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does any other array write out of bound?

Comment: You're also leaking memory by not deallocating the `obstsInBiome` before reassigning it.

Comment: who is obstsInBiome and what does the default constructor for Obstacle  look like?

Comment: @justinls my teacher (highschool) warned agains vectors when making a game, but maybe i'll try it out and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Pandrei obstsInBiome is a member of the Biome class, to store the possible obstacles to spawn in that biome. 

The obstacle class has three overloaded constructors, I'll post the code to them if nobody else can help out

Comment: @Julius, yes i realize, but obstacles can't be altered except in their constructor. But if i were to change this, would I just use the & operator?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not really familiar with memory yet to be honest, but this is the first place it's ever assigned in case that matters. Should I use delete[] before i assign it?

Comment: When you use the new operator in your constructor, the default constructor for class obstacle is called - so maybe your problem is in there.

Comment: my guess is that there's aproblem in the draw function that doesn't display the first obstacle, since the collision is handled allright

Comment: Ahhh, So I converted everything to use vectors instead of the array, and now it all works fine (plus I don't have to worry about leaking memory)! It did have something to do with the array after all, thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, in particular at where you say you think the error is, it could be in the implementation of the copy constructor for the tree.  I don't know what exactly an "Obstacle" is, nor do I know what the specific characteristics of those 4 instances are.  Perhaps the tree instance has some kind of data that doesn't copy cleanly, whereas the other 3 do.

If you aren't sure what I mean by the copy constructor, that is probably a good thing to learn about.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

Comment: All the obstacles are identical, except for their sprite. I experimented with using different obstacles in the first location, and it doesn't matter which one i use. 

But yes, yesterday was the first I've heard of the copy constructor (while reading about the rule of 3) but i didn't really understand. Looks like it'll be something I'll look more into